# Winning strategy at "Turning Turtles"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory

There is a coins games that called "[Turning Turtles](http://math450games.blogspot.com/2017/02/coin-turning-games.html)".

I'd like like to know if there is a winning strategy for this game.
From the written above I understand how to calculate the Nim-Value of it:
H=1, T=0
$HTTHTTHTHT = 1001001010$, and Nim-Value of it is: $(100)\oplus(100)\oplus(10)\oplus(10)=0$ - this is **loosing** situation (if I understand right...).

So my question is:
**How can I bring from loosing situation to a winning situation? (if it's possible)**

And I don't understand something: lets say that this is the board $HTTHTTHTHT = 1001001010$ - and it's my turn. I'm at loosing position (Nim-Val is $0$), and I can do a move that make the next player at loosing position also:
$HTTHTT\boldsymbol {T}T\boldsymbol {T}T$ - and the next player is at Nim-Val of $0$ (loosing position).
Where is my mistake here?

Thank you!

Comment: A Nim value of $0$ usually indicates a first-player losing position.  So if the other  player is good, then any move by the first player will create a winning position for the other player.

Comment: The two games seem to be different, and I interpret the statement in the first one differently.  The position has heads in positions $1,4,7,9$ so I think the Sprague-Grundy number is supposed to be $1\oplus4\oplus7\oplus9=11$.  This is just my reading of the text; I haven't confirmed it with a proof.

Comment: @Henry - you right - it was my mistake, but can you please explain more? How can I know what is the best move? Thank you!

Comment: Flip the coin in position $9$ to tails, then flip the coin in position $2$ to heads, giving $1\oplus2\oplus4\oplus7=0$

Comment: @saulspatz - if they are not the same I delete the 2nd source and I'm apologize. Can you explain please more about your example? Can it done at any series of coins?

Comment: I think that's what the text says.  As I said, I haven't proved it.  Why don't you try?  One thing to notice is that to get from $11$ to $0$, I flipped two coins ($9$ and $2$) with nim sum $11$.

Comment: @saulspatz - I try but I don't know how to "translate" it to flip coins. I saw something interesting, I add something to my question...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128256/discussion-between-cs1-and-saulspatz).

Comment: @saulspatz - which text you are talking about? From the blog?

Comment: Yes, the blog says, "Well, if we number the coins 1, 2, 3, ... from the left like in the example above, then the nim-value of a coin in position x is x if it is heads, and 0 if it is tails"  Also, I've proved this.  It's not hard.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to prove it, But how can I know which coin to flip? Can you help me with that please?

Comment: @saulspatz - I think I understand the idea. Please tell me if I'm right:  "Turning Turtles" it's like Nim, but there can be only amount once, i.e. it's impossible to have 2 piles (or more) of $4$ (for example). $x_4$ tells us if there is pile of 4 (=1) or not (=0). If we turn one coin from H to T - we remove full pile. If we turn one more coin - we actually remove only part of a pile. Did I'm right? 
Thank you!!

Comment: @CS1 The first part is right.  I don't think you can really think of it in terms the game of nim itself.  It's just uses the nim arithmetic.  Mike's answer explains it perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand two things:

1. How to translate Turning Turtles to Nim, and back.
2. What the winning strategy is in Nim.

*Turning Turtles $\iff$ Nim*

A coin with the Head side up at position $i$ is equivalent to a Nim heap of size $i$. That is, $\mathrm{H\,T\,T\,H\,T\,T\,H\,T\,H\,T}$ is equivalent to a Nim position with heaps of size $1,4,7$ and $9$.

Flipping coins numbered $i$ and $j$, where $i<j$, so that coin number $j$ was originally heads, is equivalent to reducing the Nim heap of size $j$ to a Nim heap of size $i$. For example, from $\mathrm{H\,T\,T\,H\,T\,T\,H\,T\,H\,T}$, you could flip coins number $2$ and $7$, resulting in $\mathrm{H}\,\bf{H}\,\mathrm{T\,H\,T\,T}\,\bf{T}\,\mathrm{T\,H\,T}$. If you translate both to Nim positions, this looks like
$$
(1,4,7,9)\longrightarrow (1,2,4,9),
$$
which is indeed like reducing a Nim heap of size $4$ to one of size $2$.

The **exception** to this correspondence is when both coins are turned from heads to tails. For example, moving from $\mathrm{H\,H,H}$ to $\mathrm{T\,H\,T}$. In this case, the first Nim position was $(1,2,3)$, and it seems like the result should be $(1,1,2)$, since we flipped coins $3$ and $1$. Here, we have to **mentally delete any repeated  heaps**, so instead of $(1,1,2)$, we just get a single Nim heap of size $2$. These repeated heaps do not affect the Nim outcome.

Now that you know how Turning Turtles positions and moves correspond to Nim, all you need to know is$\dots$

*Winning Strategy in Nim*

To find a winning move in a Nim position with heap size $n_1,\dots,n_k$, all you need to do is the following:

- Compute the Nim sum of the heap sizes: $m=n_1\oplus \dots \oplus n_k$. A winning move exists iff $m\neq 0$.
- Compute $n_i\oplus m$ for each $i\in \{1,\dots,k\}$. If $n_i\oplus m$ is a smaller number than $n_i$, then reducing the $n_i$ heap to $n_i\oplus m$ is a winning move.

---

*Example*

Let's find all winning moves starting from $\mathrm{H\,T\,T\,H\,T\,T\,H\,T\,H\,T}$. The corresponding Nim position is $(1,4,7,9)$, whose Nim sum is $1\oplus 4\oplus 7\oplus 9=11$. Then,

- $11\oplus 1=10$, so there is no winning move on the $1$ heap.
- $11\oplus 4=15$, so there is no winning move on the $4$ heap.
- $11\oplus 7=12$, so there is no winning move on the $7$ heap.
- $11\oplus 9=2$, so reducing the $9$ heap to $2$ is a winning move.

Translating this back to Turning Turtles, the only winning move is to flip over coins $2$ and $9$.